# WordPress : upload image from PC (Jquery )

Tags: jquery, wordpress

this is my first post here. I coded my own plugin. I have a problem with uploading file with wordpress. I can choose a file in the wordpress library, but I can not choose a file from my computer. I have the error: Sorry, you are not allowed to attach files to this content.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {


/*
    * UPLOAD IMAGE
*/

// Uploading files
var file_frame;
var wp_media_post_id = wp.media.model.settings.post.id; // Store the old id
var set_to_post_id = $('.upload_image_button').val();


$('body').on('click', '.upload_image_button', function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('slide_to_modify');

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if ( file_frame ) {
        // Set the post ID to what we want
        file_frame.uploader.uploader.param( 'post_id', set_to_post_id );
        // Open frame
        file_frame.open();
        return;
        } else {
        // Set the wp.media post id so the uploader grabs the ID we want when initialised
        wp.media.model.settings.post.id = set_to_post_id;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: '11-5 service: select a image to upload',
        button: {
            text: 'Use this image',
        },
        multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    // When an image is selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on( 'select', function() {
        // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
        attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        // Do something with attachment.id and/or attachment.url here
        $( '.slide_to_modify .image-preview').attr( 'src', attachment.url ).css( 'width', 'auto' );
        $( '.slide_to_modify .image_attachment_id').attr( 'value', attachment.id );

        $('.slide_to_modify').removeClass('slide_to_modify');

        // Restore the main post ID
        wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
    });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
});


// Restore the main ID when the add media button is pressed
jQuery( 'a.add_media' ).on( 'click', function() {
    wp.media.model.settings.post.id = wp_media_post_id;
    file_frame.close();
});
```

Comment: Follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885762/5737771

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I am not concerned by the link. I have this worry when I have the role administrator and owner of the article. In my case, I can upload an image from the wordpress library, but not from my pc.

Comment: I waited more than 24 hours, I allow myself to write a new message in order to relaunch the problem, because it is not resolved yet.